# Is it possible to access/add remote location jars to the projects using ANT build file?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ant

In my organization there is a common Jars folder in remote linux server, I want to access those jars and added to my current project path using ANT build file.

Can you please share your thoughts (whether the possible scenarios/fail case/best way to proceed), that will be nice. Thanks in adavnce.

Thanks
Srinivas

Comment: you should never ask any question which actually ask for suggestion , please try some tutorials !!!

Comment: Sure Dev, i will do. I am new to this group and i had confusion whether it's possible or not.

Comment: see try some tutorial first and if you getting some error place a question w including your code and error[stack-trace].

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to organize your jar files in a nexus http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/ repository (or any other maven repository product)

Nexus is a maven/ivy/gradle repository which you can locally install and also easily deploy jars onto them.
Very probably you know this maven repository: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j

maven, ivy and gradle are able to use this repository out of the box.
So you do not have to implement some:

- version checks to get a specific version
- a consistency check if a jar is available
- no struggling of structuring your files into folders
- also you can access the repository in many common ways (e.g. with ant-get, wget, curl and so on)
- dependency management of the transitive dependencies between your jar files

The repository setup is done by an experienced admin in about 30 mins. The population of your existing jar files depend on if there are already maven details available (a simple upload) and if not available some details have to be passed per jar file.

Comment: Thanks cilap for your insightful thoughts about the query. Here in my company they are not acquainted with this kind of setup. After investing some time, i can able to move the data from Windows to remote linux machine and Remote linux machine to windows but not with ANT task. With batch script i can able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, you can use [Ant Get Task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/get.html). It allows you to download any resources under specified URL. 
For example, in one of my projects Im downloading spnego libs from sourceforge using this task:

```
<target name="download">
        <get dest="${web-inf.dir}/lib/spengo.jar">
            <url url="http://sourceforge.net/projects/spnego/files/spnego-r7.jar"/> 
        </get>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy). Ivy is a way of handling both third party jars and jars that you build in one project that is needed in another project.

Ivy uses Maven's repository structure to search the World Wide Web for the jars you need (and the correct versions). It does dependency management which means if a jar you request depends upon another jar, Ivy will automatically download those jars too.

The nice thing about Ivy is that it works with your current Ant build system, so you don't have to redo projects and completely rewrite your build system.

The best documentation I've found on Ivy is [Ant in Action](http://www.manning.com/loughran/) by Loughran. Unfortunately, it's out of print, but it's available in Safari OnLine library and in ebook format.

Comment: Thanks David for your thought. Got to know new things, i will keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Maven too -- then get Maven Dependency From Ant using Maven Ant Tasks

[Maven Ant Tasks](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/download.cgi)